# Register services from controller in runtime .net core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, runtime, autofac, servicecollection

In my project I'm loading some dll assemblies and these assemblies contains controllers as well as services need to be injected in our DI container.

I tried to find a solutions for a days using default dotnet core DI or Autofac without any results.

I understand this is not good practice to update DI in runtime, but I hope if I can found a good solution.

I have got another way but it saves the services in config file and it is required to restart the app to load the config in beginning to register the services.

Example of my code

```
public class ServiceFactory : IServiceProvider
{
    public static IServiceCollection services { get; set; }
    public static IServiceProvider serviceProvider { get; private set; }
    static ServiceFactory()
    {
        services = new ServiceCollection();
        serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
    public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection _services)
    {
        services = _services;
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }
    public static void Register()
    {
        services.AddTransient<IRepo, Repo>();
    }
    public static void Update()
    {
        serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType);
    }
}
```

Comment: once `BuildServiceProvider` is invoked, building the provider,.any changes (additions/removals) to the services collection have no effect on the already built provider.

Comment: @Nkosi - Technically, a call to BuildServiceProvider() actually creates a new ServiceProvider with everything registered in it; but, that is a new instance at that point.

Comment: Are you trying to load from a seperate DLL/Library?

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Nkosi - Thats fine - I was just clarifying that that was the point you were making ;-)

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RobertPerry yes, I am loading a external dll file

Comment: @Nkosi yes we the service provider has been build we cannot change it because i think the whole app will use a scope created from this service provider so if we can update this scope we can update the whole system

Comment: It is also available if there are another IoC containers that allow this feature.

Comment: Let me clarify more.
the dll has controllers and there are new services need to be registered, I can register them while loading the dll, but when I try to access these controllers I get Ioc error because services not found despite i registered them but that didn't reflect on the whole system